# Salvar um JSON no banco de dados ou criar uma tabela intermediaria?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, modelagem, relacionamento

Boa noite!

Estou em um pequeno Dilema, estou construindo uma aplicação para controle de eventos,nesta aplicação eu tenho um evento que pode ter diversos convidados no Front end estou pensando em usar um componente igual a este:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Enfim, qual seria a melhor forma de salvar isso no banco? Crio uma tabela intermediária chamada "convidados" apontando para o ID do usuario e do evento ou crio um campo JSON na tabela guardando os convidados?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acredito que seria melhor o campo porque melhoraria o desempenho, imagina essa nova tabela com milhares e milhares de registros...

Comment: A melhor opção é sempre normalizar a estrutura de base de dados. Se tem uma tabela de _Agendamentos_ e outra com _Utilizadores_, o melhor será mesmo criar uma nova tabela com os _ID_ de ambos e armazenar a informação que achar necessário (neste caso o JSON).